# How to add dropdown in gridview and bind dropdown with database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to add one drop down list inside my grid view and bind with database.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter tb;
            tb = new DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = tb.GetEmpID();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "empId";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "empId";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Employee ID--", ""));
        }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter tb;
        tb = new DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = tb.GetGrid(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
        //Set the edit index.
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
        DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter tb;
        tb = new DataSet1TableAdapters.emplTableTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = tb.GetGrid(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">

<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="empId" HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="empId" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="empName" HeaderText="Employee Name" ReadOnly="True"  
  SortExpression="empName" />
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Designation" SortExpression="empDesig">
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("empDesig") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Table:

[image]

Now I am getting output like given below:

[image]

---

[image]

I need to bind drop down with db  empDesig column. Given below is a sample output design what I am acually expecting.

[image]

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-with-Selected-Value-in-EditItemTemplate-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use EditItemTemplate as shown below

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="<TextColumnNameInDataSource>" DataValueField="<ValueColumnNameInDataSource>" 
                        />

                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In normal mode you will see the control which is in ItemTemplate and when you click edit and row is in edit mode you will see whatever is in EditItemTemplate.Also both of them have DataSource,DataTextField,DataValueField attributes for populating the values in dropdownlist and SelectedValue property for showing selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Add DataKey and  onrowupdating To your aspx Gridview  and

```
    <asp:Gridview id = "dg1" onrowupdating="dg1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="ID" 

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_City" runat="server" />


            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbcity" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

      </Gridview>
```

and then on code behind  :

```
      protected void dg1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs ee)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(dg1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        TextBox contactname= (TextBox)dg1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("contact");
        DropDownList ddl_city= (DropDownList)dg1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("City");


      }  

     protected void dg1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
        { 
           if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                } 

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"> 
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Name" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>   
            </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```